# Send One Event to Multiple Topics in Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus

I want to send one event that I am receiving from  event hub to multiple topics in service bus. I am using the following code to send events to multiple topics using foreach to get topicname. 
Since it's a foreach loop I am getting latency. Is there any better way to do it.

```
foreach (var topicname in GetTopics_ActiveList(payload).Result)
                    {
                        TopicClient Client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionstring, topicname);
                       var payloadStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
                        //var msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payloadStream);

                        //BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(payloadStream, true);
                        BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(payloadStream);
                        Client.Send(message);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better way to do it.

Always. For a starter, you could cache your clients rather than creating each time. Second, use asynchronous send version of the Send method (`SendAsync`), but rather than sending one at a time, collect the tasks and await with `Task.WhenAll`. And construct your brokered message once and [clone it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.clone?view=azureservicebus-4.1.1) in the loop. Something among the lines of

```
var msg = BuildYourMessage();
var sendTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var topic in topicsCache)
{
  sendTasks.Add(client.SendAsync(msg.Clone()));
}
Tasks.WhenAll(sendTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The question I have is why do you send it to multiple topics rather than a single topic with multiple subscriptions? Perhaps you could get away with that and a single send to that topic, delegating to Azure Service Bus to perform the broadcast to all the subscriptions.

Comment: 1. I won't be able to cache my clients as it changes depends on the events I am processing. Each event goes to certain number of topics.                        
2.I can have multiple subscriptions in one topic, but when the subscription number goes up, it eventually slows down. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: I'm not sure about #2. Distribution of a message sent to a topic to the subscriptions is done on the broker. It sounds really off that it would be slower than sending individual messages to all the topics.

Comment: #2 You might be right and the other reason we using topics is because if we go with subscriptions then it doesn't have any connection string per subscription eventually we need to share connection string of topic to every listener, if they know the any other subscription name in topic they would be able to listen messages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've figured this out yet but each service bus message can have a label and you can use the type name of that event as the label then on your subscription client you can add rules to filter messages based on the label using a CorrelationFilter. A good example is the microsft eShopOnContainers example. A pretty net almost full blown website built on microservices that communicate through rabbitmq and/or service bus. Here is a link to the specific serviceBus implementation: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.cs